# Docker on java sockets : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: java, docker, sockets, networking

I have 2 java files Server.java and Client.java. Both are in separate containers.

**DOCKER FILES**: The dockerfile(in the folder named 'Server') that i use for server is:

```
FROM java:8
COPY Server.java /
RUN javac Server.java
EXPOSE 25000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["Server"]
```

The dockerfile(in the folder named 'Client') for client is:

```
FROM java:8
COPY Client.java /
RUN javac Client.java
EXPOSE 25000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["Client"]
```

**To build the cotainers i use**

```
docker build . (for the client Dockerfile)

docker build . (for the server Dockerfile)
```

**For the network setup i use**

```
docker network create client_server_network

docker run --network-alias server --network client_server_network -it serverimage

docker run --network client_server_network -it clientimage
```

**The error im getting when i run the client image is**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.2.5", 25000);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(25000);
            Socket s = ss.accept();// establishes connection
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String str = (String) dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("message= " + str);
            ss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, docker uses automatic DNS resolution between containers. Containers can resolve each other by name or alias. ([Docker bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/))

On the client side, you explicitly defined IP address of the server:
`Socket serverSocker = new Socket("192.168.2.5", 25000);`.

Docker doesn't know about it, instead of this use name or alias of the container:
`Socket serverSocker = new Socket("server", 25000);`

Or you can dynamically pass a host of the server via environment variable:
`Socket serverSocket = new Socket(System.getenv("SERVER_HOST_ENV"), 25000);`

Don't forget to pass an environment variable:
`docker run --env SERVER_HOST_ENV=server --network-alias server --network client_server_network -it server`